# TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)}.then is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm getting a strange error when trying to post with Axios.

#### JS:

```
     methods: {
        onSubmit: function () {
          axios.post('/user_token', {
            auth: {
              email: this.$refs.user_email.value,
              password: this.$refs.user_password.value
            }
            .then(response => {
              debugger
              localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.jwt)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              var err = error.response.data.errors
            })
          });
        }
      }
```

When submitting an email and password that are vaild I don't hit that debugger, instead I see this error in the console:

```
TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)}.then is not a function
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to move it outside the closing parenthesis for `post`, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: `}
            .then` -> `})
            .then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `.then()` to the outside of `.post()`. Try this:

```
 methods: {
    onSubmit: function () {
      axios.post('/user_token', {
        auth: {
          email: this.$refs.user_email.value,
          password: this.$refs.user_password.value
        }
      }).then(response => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.jwt)
      }).catch(error => {
        var err = error.response.data.errors
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Closing brace and parethese for `axios.post` should come before `.then`

Answer (score -1):

check for your array declaration and if its two dimensional array and  if u start with 
var arr = new Array ();
delete new Array and go with
var arr = [["1","A"],["2","B"]];